# QOpenGLWidget's makeCurrent does not work?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to use `QOpenGLWidget` without subclassing.

When I  try to make OpenGL calls outside of `QOpenGLWidget`'s methods or signals, nothing seems to happen. For example, following code clears window black despite me setting `glClearColor`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto glw = new QOpenGLWidget( this );
    glw->makeCurrent();
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glw->doneCurrent();

    connect( glw, &QOpenGLWidget::aboutToCompose, [=] {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    });

    setCentralWidget( glw );
}
```

However, when I move `glClearColor` inside the lambda connected to the `aboutToCompose` signal, widget is cleared with white color.

Comment: You have to wait that QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL is called before doing anything else

Comment: @Fablo, but how can I make sure that it was called without overriding it and moving my code inside?

Comment: How did you hope to do any real rendering *without* overriding [`QOpenGLWidget::initializeGL`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#initializeGL) and/or [`QOpenGLWidget::paintGL`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#paintGL) etc.?  `QOpenGLWidget` was designed to be used in a certain way.  If you try to use it it some other way you'll only make things difficult for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As essentially explained in the comments section by Fabio and G.M., **`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` won't work if called before things are setup enough**.

As of Qt 5.11 and probably other releases, [`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#makeCurrent) works by calling the [`QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#makeCurrent) method. That call only happens if the `QOpenGLWidget` is already in the initialized state however. Additionally, `QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent` can fail. The latter at least gives some indication of failure via its `bool` return parameter. Unfortunately, `QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` gives no indication at all. **`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` fails silently**.

Besides knowing this & heeding the advice in the comments, one can use the  [`QOpenGLWidget::context`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#context) method to determine whether the `QOpenGLWidget` is in the initialized state. According to the linked documentation (and as seen in practice), the `context` method returns "0 if not yet initialized" or a non-null pointer otherwise. So it's a means to determine whether or not `QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` calls `QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent` and a means to partially work around `QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` returning `void`. That's probably not particularly useful in this case, but can be useful in other related contexts so I thought this worth mentioning.

So to get `QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` to actually succeed, **`QOpenGLWidget::makeCurrent` has to be called after the `QOpenGLWidget` has been initialized in order for it to work**.

Reading between the lines of this question, it sounds as if wondering about what was needed to be done in order for GL calls to work. And as the question's author recognizes, delaying the GL calls till the `aboutToCompose` signal has been fired, works for that (at least in the context of this user's code). Another way, is to make the `QOpenGLWidget` visible, then call the GL code.

Hope this answers your question completely if not at least helpfully.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `auto *ctx = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();` to check if makeCurrent succeeded.